# How to add characters to a string in C#

Tags: c#

**Problem:** I would like add characters to a phone.

So instead of displaying ###-###-####, I would like to display (###) ###-####.

I tried the following:

```
string x = "Phone_Number";
string y = x.Remove(0,2);//removes the "1-"
```

From here, I am not sure how I would add "()" around ###

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the Masked edit? is this for Win Forms, Web or WPF? there are controls that do the formatting automagically, so there is no need for this kind of code hanky panky.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

*It's worth noting that strings are immutable in C#.. meaning that if you attempt to modify one you'll always be given a new string object.*

One route would be to convert to a number (as a sanity check) then format the string

```
var result = String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", double.Parse("8005551234"))
```

If you'd rather not do the double-conversion then you could do something like this:

```
var result = String.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", x.Substring(0 , 3), x.Substring(3, 3), x.Substring(6));
```

Or, if you already have the hyphen in place and really just want to jam in the parenthesis then you can do something like this:

```
var result = x.Insert(3, ")").Insert(0, "(");
```

Comment: `substring(0-3)` ?

Comment: typed out the answer quickly .. then came in within 2 minutes later and cleaned up any typos .. that being one of them.

Answer (score 1):

To insert string in particular position you can use `Insert` function.

Here is an example:

```
string phone = "111-222-8765";
phone = phone.Insert(0, "("); // (111-222-8765
phone = phone.Insert(3, ")"); // (111)-222-8765
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to extract the digit groups (regardless of `-` or `(`) and then output in your desired format:

```
var digitGroups = Regex.Matches(x, @"(\d{3})-?(\d{3})-?(\d{4})")[0].Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(g => g.Value).ToArray();

var ans = $"({digitGroups[0]}) {digitGroups[1]}-{digitGroups[2]}";
```

Comment: ["And now you have two problems."](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) :)

Comment: That's exactly true.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
string FormatPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(phoneNumber));

    var phoneParts = phoneNumber.Split('-');
    if (phoneParts.Length < 3)
        throw new ArgumentException("Something wrong with the input number format", nameof(phoneNumber));

    var firstChar = phoneParts[0].First();
    var lastChar = phoneParts[0].Last();
    if (firstChar == '(' && lastChar == ')')
        return phoneNumber;
    else if (firstChar == '(')
        return $"{phoneParts[0]})-{phoneParts[1]}-{phoneParts[2]}";
    else if (lastChar == ')') 
        return $"({phoneParts[0]}-{phoneParts[1]}-{phoneParts[2]}";

    return $"({phoneParts[0]})-{phoneParts[1]}-{phoneParts[2]}";
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
string n = "123-123-1234";
var formattedPhoneNumber = FormatPhoneNumber(n);
```