# Add And Remove Character in a String

Tags: c#

**Problem:** I would like add characters to a phone.

So instead of displaying ###-###-####, I would like to display (###) ###-####.

I tried the following:

```
string x = "Phone_Number";
string y = x.Remove(0,2);//removes the "1-"
string z = y.Insert(0,"(");
z = z.Insert(4,")");
```

From here, I am not sure how I would remove the first "-" so it displays the following:(###) ###-####

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the `string.Format()` method. It accepts patterns.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst That's not going to help the OP get rid of any characters in the string.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the 5 answers on the exact same question you posted 45 mins ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686985/how-to-add-characters-to-a-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: @itsme86: get the digits out of the phone number and use `string.Format()` as per desired formatting rule. Done.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Yes, but you just glossed over half of the question. It's like "How do you bake a cake?" "Easy! You stick it in the oven until it's ready"

Comment: @itsme86: It was a comment, not a full answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Following your logic, you can add:

```
z = z.Remove(5,1);
z = z.Insert(5," ");
```

Notice that you don't have to declare a new variable for each step. Simply reuse the same variable like I did.

However, you can do the whole thing in a different way. You can split the string on the hyphens "-" and the concatenate them as you wish:

```
string x = "Phone_Number";
string[] xx = x.Split("-");
x = "(" + xx[1] + ") " + xx[2] + "-" xx[3];
```

I ignored `xx[0]` because it seems you didn't want the first part "1-".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert any number to a (###)-###-########## format, I would suggest the following snippet:

```
string x = "123-456-7890";
x = Regex.Replace(x, @"[^0-9]", "");
x = $"({x.Substring(0, 3)})-{x.Substring(3, 3)}-{x.Substring(6)}";
```

Edit: to also make sure that "smaller" numbers work, the following ensures that 1-6 characters work as well (replace the last line of the previous part):

```
if(x.Length <= 3)
  x = $"({x.Substring(0)})";
else if(x.Length <= 6)
  x = $"({x.Substring(0, 3)})-{x.Substring(3)}";
else
  x = $"({x.Substring(0, 3)})-{x.Substring(3, 3)}-{x.Substring(6)}";
```